# attribute that is a list behave weirdly with inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance, super

If you compile this python code, what output do you think you'll get?

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(o,ls = []):
        o.list_truc = ls

class Truc:
    def __init__(o):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(o):
        super().__init__()

obj1 = Child() 
obj1.list_truc.append(Truc())
obj2 = Child()
obj2.list_truc.append(Truc())

print(len(obj2.list_truc))
```

> ! the answer is 2. But how does that makes sense? can someone explain this to me? obj2.list_truc is supposed to be empty at creation right? But it isn't. Also, changing the 3rd line to :
> o.list_truc = []
> change something which is incomprehensible to me

Comment: `ls=[]` is evaluated once when the class is created, so only one list is ever created. If you make use of it, all the class instances will share that one list. See the dupe for how to correct this. It doesn't use a class, but classes aren't relevant here.

Comment: thanks a lot i get it but it's very unintuitive behavior. you would think ls = [] is evaluated everytime the constructor is called

Comment: Thus the title of the linked question and the sentiment in that post. This is definitely one of Python's least intuitive design decisions.